# 'Library' with detailed page

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Quick little question. I'm a true beginner in Android, so bear with me.

I need to make a sort-of-library activity. It needs to have a list of around 30 keywords, when you click the keyword it goes to another screen and provides content (and maybe a picture). For example: *keyword:* London *content*: This is the city of blabla. As easy is that.

What's the easiest way to do this? Any links or example code would be really awesome! A simple answer would also help ofcourse.

Comment: the easiest way is to pay someone for doing this for you ... if you don't wana do this ... you have to learn java and android

Comment: Well that's really helpfull, captain obvious. I ofcourse meant like with what sort of method, with SQlite, listview or..?

Comment: SQlite - maybe or maybe online, depends on your needs, ListView - yes ... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/ the detail page only contains the same title though, but the answer of Rajesh seems to be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse with ADT, you could use the Master/Detail Flow from the "New Android Application" wizard, which you can start by New -> Android Application Project.

Comment: Looking into it atm! Seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

First: Check if your new project already created the `activity_main.xml`, if not, Create a `Android XML Layout` inside the `/res/layout` folder to later assign to your `Activity`, name it `activity_main.xml`.

In the layout you can add `LinearLayout`'s within `TextView`'s or whatever you want to represent that keywords.

**Note 1:** Name the `android:id=""` of them easy to remember because you will use them on your code later.

Now goto the `onCreate` method of your `MainActivity.java` and write this line of code:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.main_activity.xml);
```

Goto the top of your `MainActivity.java` and just after the class declaration, declare the variables of your elements that you created in the `activity_main.xml` like:

```
LinearLayout londonKeywordLayout = null; 
TextView     londonKeyword       = null;

LinearLayout anotherKeywordLayout = null; 
TextView     anotherKeyword       = null;

String TitleString;
String DetailString;
String ImgPathString;
```

Don't forget to include the `LinearLayout` and `TextView` imports. You can use Ctrl + Shift + O to automatically do the imports.

Then, back to the `onCreate` method and assign the variables to your elements of your `activity_main.xml` this way:

```
londonKeywordLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.londonKeywordLayoutID);
londonKeyword       = (TextView)     findViewById(R.id.londonKeywordID);
```

`"londonKeywordLayoutID"` for example, should be your id as i said on Note 1, change if necessary.

Then, you need to create a `DetailActivity` to handle and show all keywords detail, using the same method i told you above.

Then, just after assigning you can set the `onClick` event to open the details `Activity`.

```
OnClickListener keywordListener = new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == 1){
      DetailString  = "London details";
      TitleString   = "London.";
      ImgPathString = "the path to london img"; 
    }
    if (v.getId() == 2){
      DetailString  = "another details";
      TitleString   = "another.";
      ImgPathString = "the path to another img";         
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(this,DetailActivity.class)
    i.putExtra("DETAILTEXT", DetailString);
    i.putExtra("TITLE", TitleString);
    i.putExtra("IMAGEPATH", ImgPathString);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);

  }
};

londonKeywordLayout.setOnClickListener(keywordListener);
londonKeywordLayout.setId(1) //1 for london.
anotherKeywordLayout.setOnClickListener(keywordListener);
anotherKeywordLayout.setId(2) //2 for another.
```

Do this same thing to the all other keywords.

In the `DetailActivity.java` do the all thing i explained here above about creating xml and declaring layouts and textviews but at this time create just one it will be used to all keywords, it will be dinamically. declare these variables after the class declaration:

```
String detailText;
String titleText;
String imgPath;
```

you should go to `onCreate` method and get the values you did send by `Intent` this way:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    detailText    = extras.getString("DETAILTEXT");
    titleText     = extras.getString("TITLE");
    imgPath       = extras.getString("IMAGEPATH");
```

Then, you have to use `.setText(detailText)` to the title `TextView` of the `DetailActivity`, and do the same with the other strings, and handle the image creating a `Drawing`.

Basically is that, any help, comment here, and i'll try to help you.

Good luck.

Comment: If I understand this method completely, wouldn't this method give me 30 activities (1 for every keyword)? Thanks for the detailed answer though.

Comment: Oh, you're right. i think that its too many activities, well, i will edit the answer now to using only one activity to all keywords, wait a min.

Comment: @user2883477 edited my answer, see it

Comment: Really usefull! I think I prefer a listview though. But this helps me with altering the code for the listview correctly! Thanks.